# how to use IF statement inside a ajax script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to make my datetime font color turn into red when the date is <= datetime.now
any idea how to put if statement inside ajax ?

here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#customerTable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "Customer/AjaxHandler",
        "bProcessing" : true,
        "aoColumns": [
            {"sName": "CustomerId", "bVisible":false},
            {"sName": "NamaPerusahaan",
             "bSearchable": true,
             "bSortable": true,
             "fnRender": function (oObj){
                 return '<a href="/Customer/Details/' +
                     oObj.aData[0] + '">' + oObj.aData[1] + '</a>';
             }
            },
            {"sName": "Alamat1"},
            {"sName": "Telephone"},
            //below is the datetime
            {"sName": "TglNonAktif"},
            {"sName": "Edit",
             "bSearchable": false,
             "bSortable": false,
             "fnRender": function (oObj){
                 return '<a href="/Customer/Edit/' + oObj.aData[0] + '" class="btn mini blue"><i class="icon-edit"></i>Edit</a>';
             }
            },
            {"sName": "Delete",
             "bSearchable": false,
             "bSortable": false,
             "fnRender": function (oObj){
                 return '<a href="/Customer/Edit/' + oObj.aData[0] + '" class="btn mini red"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Delete</a>';
             }
            }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is the controller

```
public ActionResult AjaxHandler(JkueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
IEnumerable<Customer> filteredCustomers;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch)
{
var nameFilter = Convert.ToString(Reguest["sSearch_1"]);
var isAlamatSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Reguest["sSearch_2"]);
var townFilter = Convert.ToString(Reguest["sSearch_3"]);

filteredCustomers = db.Customers.Where(c => isNamaPerusahaanSearchable && c.NamaPerusahaan.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())|| isNamaPerusahaanSearchable && c.Alamat1.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())|| isTelephoneSearchable && c.Telephone.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()));
}
else
{
filteredCustomers = db.Customers;
}
var isNameSortable = Convert.ToBoolean (Reguest["bSortable_1"]);
var isAddresSortable = Convert.ToBoolean (Reguest["bSortable_2"]);
var isTownSortable = Convert.ToBoolean (Reguest["bSortable_3"]);
var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32 (Reguest["iSortCol_0"]);

Func<Customer, Obkect> orderingFunction;
switch(sortColumnIndex)
{
case 1:
orderingFunction = (x => isNameSortable ? x.NamaPerusahaan:"");
default:
orderingFunction = (x => isNameSortable ? x.NamaPerusahaan:"");
break;
}

var sortDirection = Reguest["sSortDir_0"];
if (sortDirection == "asc")
filteredCustomers = filteredCustomers.OrderBy (orderingFunction);
else
filteredCustomers = filteredCustomers.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);

var displayedCustomers = filteredCustomers.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
var result = from c in displayedCustomers select new [] { Convert.ToString(c.CustomerId), c.NamaPerusahaan, c.Alamat1, c.Telephone, c.TglNonAktif.ToShortDateString(), "Edit", "Delete"};

return Json (new
{ 
sEcho = param.sEcho,
iTotalRecords = db.Customers.Count(),
iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredCustomers.Count(),
aaData = result
},
JsonReguestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

any answer may helpfull :D
regards

Comment: You have a missing quote before `aoColumns`

Comment: Sure no problem to put it in, but where is the date variable?

Comment: thx for the correction,i just forget type the quote in my question,but in my code everything work fine :D

Comment: @PHPglue do u mean the ajax in my controller ?

Comment: @silver "sName": "TglNonAktif" is the date variable, how to type the if inside this code :D

Comment: @ericthesialie: that isn't a date, where does your code convert that into a date we can do something with?

Comment: i have this in my controller........    var result = from c in displayedCustomers select new [] {convert.tostring c.tglnonaktif.toshortdatestring()}

Comment: i have add the ajax in my controller :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are constructing a JavaScript object literal and want one field to have a different value according to dynamic condition, then you can:

For simple conditions / if statements—Use the ternary operator:

```
{
    "color": (date <= datetime) ? "red" : "black",
    ...
}
```

---

For more complicated conditions, things with more than two choices, etc., use an anonymous function:

```
{
    "color": (function() { if (...) return "red"; else return "black"; })(),
    ...
}
```

The code between the parentheses declares a function inline, then immediately evaluates it. The evaluation returns an arbitrary result depending on the body of the function. The result will simply be a value corresponding to a given object key.

---

I can update the JSON/ajax code if you answer @silver's question regarding where the date (and color) variables are.

Comment: A more concise way would be a conditional expression.

Comment: You are correct, for a simple `if`-`else` a conditional expression would be sufficient. I'll update my answer.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you want to be putting this code in the `.dataTable({ ... })` declaration. Is that the part that decides the color?

Comment: the date variables are the TglNonAktif,i want to make this date font become red when the date is <= datetime.now                              and yes that the part decides the color

Comment: Please don't call that "JSON object". If any, it's an object literal. The JSON object syntax doesn't allow arbitrary JS expressions.

Comment: @ericthesialie I see I might have misunderstood the question altogether.  This is less of a jQuery/AJAX question and more of a jQuery dataTable question. Its a custom plugin that I am unfamiliar with. It seems that dataTable defines the bindings on its own (?) and updates objects whenever there's a change?    I would simply read up the documentation on datatables.net

Comment: @FelixKling sounds good. I meant that it evaluates into a JSON-like JavaScript object in the end, but even that is not a very kosher statement.

Comment: well,so i put the wrong title ~_~                                                                   is there any easy way to make "sName": "TglNonAktif" become red if the date is <= today ?  or should i put my controller code too ?

Comment: I don't know much about dataTable. See this conversation seems to have some potential: (http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/717/conditional-format).